# Path references in QueryDSL join to subquery

Tags: sql, orm, querydsl

I'd like to know the best way to implement this query in SQL-style QueryDSL which joins to a subquery. I struggled a bit, but got it to generate the necessary SQL.  I'm wondering if there are any simplifications/improvements, however, particularly related to the three "paths" I had to create? For example, would be great to define latestCaseId in terms of latestSubQuery.

In the simplified form of my actual query below, I am finding the set of records (fields spread across `ucm` and `pcm`) which have the latest timestamp per case group.  The subquery identifies the latest timestamp per group so that we can filter the outer query by it.

```
  final SimplePath<ListSubQuery> latestSubQueryPath = Expressions.path(ListSubQuery.class, "latest");
  final SimplePath<Timestamp> caseLatestMentioned = Expressions.path(Timestamp.class, "caseLatestMentioned");
  final SimplePath<Integer> latestCaseId = Expressions.path(Integer.class, "latest.caseId");

  final ListSubQuery<Tuple> latest = new SQLSubQuery()
          .from(ucm2)
          .innerJoin(pcm2).on(ucm2.id.eq(pcm2.id))
          .groupBy(pcm2.caseId)
          .list(pcm2.caseId.as(latestCaseId), ucm2.lastExtracted.max().as(caseLatestMentioned));

  q.from(ucm)
          .join(pcm).on(ucm.id.eq(pcm.id))
          .innerJoin(latest, latestSubQueryPath).on(pcm.caseId.eq(latestCaseId))
          .where(ucm.lastExtracted.eq(caseLatestMentioned));
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could use the `.get(<various Path impls>)` method of `PathBuilder`. The way I like to think of it is that creating `final PathBuilder<Tuple> latestSubQueryPath = new PathBuilder<>(Tuple.class, "latest")` and joining to it `.innerJoin(latest, latestSubQueryPath)` is creating an alias for the subquery. Then you can use `.get(<various Path impls>)` to access the fields as follows:

```
  q.from(ucm)
          .join(pcm).on(ucm.id.eq(pcm.id))
          .innerJoin(latest, latestSubQueryPath).on(pcm.caseId.eq(latestSubQueryPath.get(pcm2.caseId)))
          .where(ucm.lastExtracted.eq(latestSubQueryPath.get(maxLastExtractedDate)));
```

I've not run the code but hopefully this is in the right direction. If not, I'll have a look tomorrow when I have the relevant codebase to hand.

Update: As mentioned in the comments, `ucm2.lastExtracted.max()` requires an alias. I've called it `maxLastExtractedDate` and assume it's used to alias `ucm2.lastExtracted.max()` when creating the subquery.

Comment: This was very helpful and all worked, except for the `ucm2.lastExtracted.max()` part. Nor did moving `.max()` outside those parens; this seems to require an explicit alias?

Comment: I genuinely thought as much when replying. As you say aliasing the value will solve the problem. I don't believe there is a cleaner way.